# Can not read from a pipe, and another stdin issue

Tags: c, redirect, pipe, posix, stdin

So, I asked here just a while ago, but half of that question was just me being dumb. And I still have issues. I hope that this will be clearer than the question before.

I'm writing POSIX `cat`, I nearly got it working, but I have couple of issues:

1. My `cat` can not read from a pipe and I really do not know why (redirecting (`<`) works fine)
2. I can not figure out how to make it continuously read stdin, without some issues. I had a version that worked "fine", but would create a stack-overflow. The other version wouldn't stop reading from stdin if there was only stdin i.e.: `my-cat < file` would read from stdin until it got terminated which it shouldn't, but it has to read from stdin and wait for termination if no files are suplied.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "u")) != EOF) {
        switch(opt) {
            case 'u':
                /* Make the output un-buffered */
                setbuf(stdout, NULL);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    int i = 0, fildes, fs = 0;

    do {
        /* Check for operands, if none or operand = "-". Read from stdin */
        if (argc == 0 || !strcmp(argv[i], "-")) {
            fildes = STDIN_FILENO;
        } else {
            fildes = open(argv[i], O_RDONLY);
        }

        /* Check for directories */
        struct stat fb;
        if (!fstat(fildes, &fb) && S_ISDIR(fb.st_mode)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "pcat: %s: Is a directory\n", argv[i]);
            i++;
            continue;
        }

        /* Get file size */
        fs = fb.st_size;

        /* If bytes are read, write them to stdout */
        char *buf = malloc(fs * sizeof(char));
        while ((read(fildes, buf, fs)) > 0)
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, fs);

        free(buf);

        /* Close file if it's not stdin */
        if (fildes != STDIN_FILENO)
            close(fildes);

        i++;
    } while (i < argc);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the size of a pipe?

Comment: Oh, and why are you using `setbuf()` on `stdout` and then bypassing stdio with your writes? What's the point to the former?

Comment: @Shawn I used `printf`, but then I rewrote practically the whole thing and left it there

Comment: cat doesn't check for directories.... In linux cat cannot `read(2)` from directories, so that results in an error... in BSDs cat perfectly reads directories and outputs their binary data.

Comment: I should use stdio, that copes with buffering and you have used setbuf(NULL) for processing option `-u`  what is the way you plan to unbuffer? just setting `setbuf(NULL)` and then using no stdio at all?  I don't understand.

Comment: The size of a fifo is the amount of data that has been written to it, but has not yet read from the reader process.  I don't know what do you need this for, but that's the thing.

Comment: @user419050, I don't  understand what do you mean with _can not read from a pipe and I really do not know why (redirecting (<) works fine)_  Can you explain?  (reading from a pipe must work always you are reading from stdin) I think what you don't understand is not a pipe, but what is redirection exactly.

Comment: @LuisColorado The problem was that I was using the filesize as a buffer, but pipes do not have a file size, using fixed size buffer solves this issue. If I implemented some error checking i would have figured it out on my own, but i didn't

Comment: pipes are empty when you start using them.... this is why they show 0 as the size.  I'm glad that you have solved the issue.... congrats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipes don't have a size, and nor do terminals.  The contents of the `st_size` field is undefined for such files.  (On my system it seems to always contain 0, but I don't think there is any cross-platform guarantee of that.)

So your plan of reading the entire file at one go and writing it all out again is not workable for non-regular files, and is risky even for them (the read is not guaranteed to return the full number of bytes requested).  It's also an unnecessary memory hog if the file is large.

A better strategy is to read into a fixed-size buffer, and write out only the number of bytes you successfully read.  You repeat this until end-of-file is reached, which is indicated by `read()` returning 0.  This is how you solve your second problem.

On a similar note, `write()` is not guaranteed to write out the full number of bytes you asked it to, so you need to check its return value, and if it was short, try again to write out the remaining bytes.

Here's an example:

```
#define BUFSIZE 65536  // arbitrary choice, can be tuned for performance

ssize_t nread;
char buf[BUFSIZE]; // or char *buf = malloc(BUFSIZE);
while ((nread = read(filedes, buf, BUFSIZE)) > 0) {
    ssize_t written = 0;
    while (written < nread) {
        ssize_t ret = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf + written, nread - written);
        if (ret <= 0)
            // handle error
        written += ret;
    }
}
if (nread < 0)
    // handle error
```

As a final comment, your program lacks error checking in general; e.g. if the file cannot be opened, it will proceed anyway with `filedes == -1`.  It is important to check the return value of every system call you issue, and handle errors accordingly.  This would be essential for a program to be used in real life, and even for toy programs created just as an exercise, it will be very helpful in debugging them.  (Error checking would probably have given you some clues in figuring out what was wrong with this program, for instance.)

Comment: I wanted to add some error checking later, but yea that probably wasn't a good idea. I think that I understand most of the code, but I have couple of questions. Why are you keeping track of the written bytes? Shouldn't just `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nread);` work just as well? Also I'm probably just dumb, but what does `buf + written` and `nread - written` do exactly? And last, why are you adding the return value of `write()` to the `written` bytes?

Comment: @user419050: Like I said, "write() is not guaranteed to write out the full number of bytes you asked it to".  This is explained in the man page.  It returns the number of bytes it did successfully write.  We keep track of the total successfully written with the `written` variable.  Then `buf+written` points to the first byte that has not yet been written, and `nread - written` is the number that we still need to write.

Comment: @user419050: `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nread);` would be okay for a first try, but we'd then need a follow-up loop in case it returned less than `nread`.  The approach I gave avoids having to call `write()` in two places by making the first try part of the same loop.  Note that the first time through the inner loop, when `written == 0`, we are indeed doing `write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nread);`, and if it returns `nread`, the loop will terminate without iterating again.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I will leave this "unsolved" for a while to see if someone else can help me with the second issue or not

Comment: The code I gave should correctly read from stdin continuously until end-of-file (Ctrl-D).  Is that not what your second issue was about?

Comment: Yea it does solve the issue, I thought that it was something about my for loop, and not the read and write part. Thanks!

Comment: @NateEldredge, write is not waranted to `write()` all in one shot in network connections and things like those... for writing fifos and files the process is blocked until full write finishes.... because the write must be atomic and the inode is locked for the full write call.  This is the scenario in which cat moves on.  The explanation you give is not incorrect, and the inner loop doesn't hurt, but out of scope here.

Comment: @LuisColorado: There are ways to get a short write on a regular file or pipe: full disk, quota hit, non-restarted signal, etc.  I agree they're not strictly necessary to handle in a learning exercise, but I think it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: @LuisColorado: Real-world `cat`s do loop on the write, e.g. [openbsd](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/3893b88e79e309ab67702bb718f8664df65b4d81/bin/cat/cat.c#L239).

Comment: Yes, but in that case you get a short write and the next will receive an error (-1 and errno will tell you what happens)  there-s no difference in that case of trying to write in this read or in the next to get the error.

Comment: real world cat's are (you said) real world, and can be used in socket connections or anything.  but the literature is full of places where is said that writes are written in full normally in one shot if the output is a file in the filesystem or then you will get an error in the next write.  As you say, this is a learn exercise, where stdio is more than perfect to hold filesystem dependent best buffer size and not "arbitrarily fixed to some number"

Answer (score 1):

Your `cat` (You can call it `my-cat`, but I preferred to call it `felix`, just permit me the pun) should be used with `stdio` all the time to get the benefit of the buffering done by the `stdio` package.  Below is a simplified version of `cat` using exclusively `stdio` package (almost exactly equal as it appears in K&R) and you'll see that is completely efficient as shown (you will see that the structure is almost exactly as yours, but I simplify the processing of the data copy /like K&R book/ and the processing of arguments /yours is a bit meshy/):

#### felix.c

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

#define ERR(_code, _fmt, ...) do {            \
        fprintf(stderr,"%s: " _fmt, progname, \
                ##__VA_ARGS__);               \
        if (_code) exit(_code);               \
    } while (0)

char *progname = "cat";

void process(FILE *f);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "u")) != EOF) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'u': setbuf(stdout, NULL); break;
        }
    }

    /* for the case it has been renamed, calculate the basename
     * of argv[0] (progname is used in the macro ERR above) */
    progname = strrchr(argv[0], '/');
    progname = progname
             ? progname + 1
             : argv[0];

    /* shift options */
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if (argc) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            FILE *f = fopen(argv[i], "r");
            if (!f) {
                ERR(EXIT_FAILURE,
                    "%s: %s (errno = %d)\n",
                    argv[i], strerror(errno), errno);
            }
            process(f);
            fclose(f);
        }
    } else {
        process(stdin);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/* you don't need to complicate here, fgetc and putchar use buffering as you stated in main
 * (no output buffering if you do the setbuf(NULL) and input buffering all the time).  The buffer
 * size is best to leave stdio to calculate it, as it queries the filesystem to get the best
 * input/output size and create buffers this size. and the processing is simple with a loop like
 * the one below. You'll get no appreciable difference between this and any other input/output.
 * you can believe me, I've tested it. */
void process(FILE *f)
{
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF) {
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

As you see, nothing has been specially done to support redirection, as redirection is not done inside a program, but done by the program that calls it (in this case by the shell)  When you start a program, you receive three already open file descriptors.  These are the ones that the shell is using, or the ones that the shell just puts in the places of 0, 1, and 2 before starting your program.  So your program has nothing to do to cope with redirection.  Everything is done (in this case) in the shell... and this is why your program redirection works, even if you have not done anything for it to work. You have only to do redirection if you are going to call a program with its input, output or standard error redirected somewhere (and this somewhere is not the standard input, output or error you have received from your parent process)... but this is not the case of my-cat.